# transpose horizontal data and save them

Tags: python, file, numpy

I have a simple code whose idea is to open a six-column file, pick one column and save it. The problem I am facing is that I continuously get horizontally arranged data. When I tried to transpose them, I got an even more weird output that looked like

```
[number1, number2, number3, ..., number4, number5, number6]
```

Although there are one million points in a column. How can I get around this problem?

```
import numpy as np

filename = "C:\\Users\\blablabla.dat"
col_sep = "\t"

col_1 = []

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] != "#":
            linedata = [float(line.split(col_sep)[i]) for i in range(len(line.split(col_sep)))]
            col_1.append(linedata[4])

tr = np.transpose(col_1)

s = str(tr)
c = open("C:\\Users\\blablabla1.dat", "w")
c.write(s)
c.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are trying to extract one column from a file and save it to another file?

This should do it:

```
filename = "C:\\Users\\blablabla.dat"
col_sep = "\t"

col_1 = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] != "#":
            col_1.append(float(line.split(col_sep)[4]))

with open("C:\\Users\\blablabla1.dat", "w") as f:
    for val in col_1:
        f.write("%f\n" % val)
```

The `list` called `col_1` in your program has no attached orientation, it's neither horizontal, nor vertical; it's just a list of values. You are populating it with values from a particular column, reading a file line by line and parsing manually. To save it as a column, you have to iterate it in the same manner and write one value per line.

Additionally, just to demystify what was going on; `np.transpose` did nothing on your one-dimensional data, simply returning an `np.array` (vector) with data from your `list`. `str` on that returned a human-readable string representation of that `array`, which you wrote to the output file.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I see your approach is easy and straightforward. Could you explain why the transposing didn't work?

Comment: `transpose` switches axes; if there is only one axis, switching it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `np.transpose` (which is a no-op for 1D data) you could simply add a dimension after converting it to an array:

```
tr = np.array(col_1)[:, None]  # instead of "tr = np.transpose(col_1)"
```

For example:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])[:, None]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

There are several other ways to improve your code but that change should fix the problem. :)

For example [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy-loadtxt) could be used to extract the column in a much more straight-forward manner:

```
# to extract the fifth column of a csv file:
tr = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=col_sep, comments='#')[:, 4][:, None]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too! The list can now be transposed.

Comment: @DenGor No problem. Please don't forget to [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) all helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

`file.write('\n'.join([str(_) for _ in col_1]) + '\n')` may work for you.

By the way `numpy.ndarray` objects can't be written to files directly, try `numpy.savetxt()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.loadtxt()` to read the entire input table into a `numpy` array and then save individual columns using `numpy.savetxt` as columns in different output files, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(filename).T
output_filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', ...] # add 3 more names
for col, fn in zip(data, output_filenames):
    np.savetxt(fn, col)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: You shouldn't delete it, you should edit it to add some explanation.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I thought the code is simple enough to be self-explanatory. However, if you have trouble understanding any part of it, please post your specific question here and I will try to address it.

Comment: I don't have trouble understanding it, it's just that code-only answers are usually considered low quality. [Your post was in the low quality posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16722498), which is why I commented on it. So I recommend you add some explanation, but if you really think that it doesn't need any, you can leave your answer as it is.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for explanation. Obviously the machine is not alone in thinking this is a low quality answer as reflected by the number of votes :)